# Array.push method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and javascript as whole. I want to receive data from the server and render it on the front-end. the data I get is in array form, so I loop through the data to save it to an array and then loop back through the array to render the elements in un-ordered list. when I console.log() the data, it shows what I receive but when I console.log() the length of array it shows 0 and doesn't add what I receive. if any clue please, please respond. any help would be really appreciated.thanks

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.notes = [];
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/getnotes')

    .then(response =>{
        response.data.forEach((note)=>{
                console.log(note.title), 
                this.notes.push(note) // something isn't quite right here
            }
        )
    });
    console.log(this.notes.length);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul><li>default li</li>
                {
                    this.notes.map((note)=>{
                        return(
                            <li>
                                {note.title}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: may the comma after console.log(note.title),  should be ; -> console.log(note.title);

Comment: are you sure that this.notes exist inside foreach. this refer to response data? may the var should declare external and use notes.push(note) without this.

Answer (score 0):

Data received from server is async in nature, so you won't be able to see `this.notes.length` right after sending off the ajax request

I'd suggest you store results from the server in the state and let React update the DOM when state changes, updated code below:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    // this.notes = [];
    this.state = {
        notes: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/getnotes')

    .then(response =>{
        this.setState({
            notes: response.data
        });
        //response.data.forEach((note)=>{
        //      console.log(note.title), 
        //      this.notes.push(note) // something isn't quite right here

        //}
        //)
    });
    console.log(this.notes.length);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul><li>default li</li>
                {
                    this.state.notes.map((note)=>{
                        return(
                            <li>
                                {note.title}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put notes in the state of the component, and update it using setState.

Comment: how didn't I thought about it. thanks